# How to transfer data from one site to another without MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, database

I have two sites, Site A and Site B. Both are simple PHP sites with no MySQL. They both are on different servers.

Scenario:

- A request for username/password is made on Site A. Site A is supposed to email this username/password to admin's email to show that a request has been made to create user.
- The request to create username/password made on Site A is to be sent to Site B and a username/password should be created on Site B.
- User can login through this information in Site B for next 24 hours.

On Site B, there is already system that logs in people with username/passwords store in arrays.

My problem:

Basically everything is clear except two things.

- How can I efficiently send the (let's say `<form>` variables username/pwd) from Site A and Site B?
- After I receive username/pwd in Site B through some way, what's the most efficient way I can store this information? Filing? Or some other way so that I can use this information to log in users on Site B?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php. You need to look into PHP's cURL functions - these are designed to assemble and send requests over the network. If you're passing around sensitive information (usernames and passwords) then these requests really need to happen over https or some other secure protocol. If you're storing usernames and passwords for your site in an array then you won't be able to create users dynamically.

So, you'll need to switch your Site B to use a database to store user information. There are several different API setups for transferring data over the internet. RESTful APIs are probably the easiest that I know of to implement. On the whole, this is a rather large project to do correctly, especially so if you have limited experience. There are basic examples of how to use curl in the link. You don't really have to use a formal API but it's good if other people will be communicating with it at some point.

In summary: PHP is capable of making requests to other websites just like your browser does. It can do this with curl functions (and others) - and like other requests you can access the information in $_POST and `$_GET` variables in the receiving script. Sometimes information is transferred with GET requests but is transferred as part of the URL in a way that PHP doesn't recognize by default. In that case you need to manually parse out the info using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable.

There's really nothing incredibly special about the whole setup - with GET you're sending data as part of the url. With POST you're sending it along with the request (the URL is part of the request but POST data is not as 'noisy' because it's not stored in your website history and typically not stored in server logs). Internally this whole process happens via the transmission of headers. If you're not familiar, you should look into them and also into how the underlying machinery of HTTP works. This is the same kind of process that your browser goes through each time you visit a website - but your browser hides the details from you.

**NOTE**: I'm not attempting to explain an implementation here. My interpretation of this question is that it's a very broad question. Therefore, I'm trying to give you an overview of how this kind of thing works in general. https will establish a secured channel of communication between the two servers but won't validate the identity of Site A therefore some kind of secure authentication mechanism is needed. Similarly, you'll need some kind of secure authentication for any sites that are capable of logging in users. I encourage you to research web authentication and http fundamentals.

Comment: How does the target server determine that the incoming request is legitimate?

Comment: To answer my own question, I did think that IP filtering would be a simple approach, but it would be easily defeated if server A was on a shared server - an attacker would just purchase an account on the same box.

Comment: "you'll need to switch your Site B to use a database to store user information". Sorry to pick another hole, but this isn't critical to the problem at hand. User records can be stored in a single flat file, or one file per user. I agree that a database is a much better idea, but the OP doesn't seem to have that facility.

Comment: You can store user accounts in a flat file but it's going to be inefficient and it's not going to scale. DBs exist for a reason. @Steve if you don't have a database available on your server consider something like sqlite which scales much better than flat files.

Comment: @halfer, Also, saying "this answer is incorrect" is not the same thing as giving an answer.

Comment: Yes, flat files are not going to scale, I agree - I was referring to the "need" to switch to a database. I wouldn't say your answer is incorrect (and I haven't, either) but thought some comments might be helpful. It's very usual here for people to add thoughts or critiques to an answer.

Comment: @halfer, You're being picky - I like that. However, you're doing it wrong. Suggesting solutions that you know are bad is not a constructive way to comment. For instance, one possibility that we both missed would be to store the data as text in an image. Then you could use OCR to extract the user's info. While possible, this is not a good solution - so I have omitted it. It's not the comment that really bothered me though - it's the tone. You're presenting something that's not really a viable solution as a 'hole' in my answer. So, please consider your tone when making such hypotheticals.

Comment: I think you have taken my small criticisms, which were intended as friendly and constructive, too personally. The security issue is not insignificant. I'll leave it there though, and wish you a pleasant day, genuinely.

Comment: @halfer, Indeed, I did take them too personally. I try to think through my answers carefully and so can be overly defensive of them. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a [similar question before here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324950/472495), I seem to recall. It's very slightly different because you don't have a database, but the principles are much the same: you need a Single Sign On (SSO) system.

You can build one yourself: each site has a shared secret used for hashing and/or encryption. Let's say that a user logs successfully into site A. They then do something that causes site B to generate a username/password for them, so site B needs a way to differentiate genuine requests from fraudulent ones.

You could generate a hash on site A thus:

> hash = hash_func(shared_secret + timestamp + user_email)

We then pass these things to site B in a redirect:

> https://siteb.tld/auth?timestamp=123454321&email=joe@example.com&hash=78g2gb2bg2kguigigbg2

Site B then uses the shared_secret (from its own data store) and the supplied pieces of information to recreate the hash. If it matches, it is deemed authenticated. It can then generate a random password and email that to the user.

For security, this should be done over SSL, as my link implies. Email addresses should not be carried in plaintext query strings for reasons of privacy - whilst they are not immune from interception in POST operations, less devices (browsers, servers) will routinely log them.

You don't have to pass the timestamp - if the system clocks are NTP synchronised, then you can round to the nearest ten seconds and then calculate the hash for either side of the rounding on the target server. That can improve security, as it is less obvious how you are creating the hash.

Don't use MD5, SHA1 or other fast hashes - use something more complex. And make sure you prevent large numbers of attempts in site B from a single IP address (maybe 30 per IP per hour?). That will prevent brute-force attempts to get into site B via the back door.