# Allow login to website only if request comes from another specific website

Tags: php, authentication, referrer

I have a PHP/MySQL website (website 1) that has a login system that only asks for a PIN code (just a long numeric string). A user has 2 ways of login in with this code:

1. Going to the website 1 login page and enter the code in a typical login form
2. Clicking in website 2 on a link that carries his PIN code as a GET value. The link has the format http://myURL.com/login.php?pin=123456789. That just calls a function that receives the PIN as a parameter and processes the login. **Website 2 is located in a different domain/server than website 1**.

Until here everything works fine.

Now come's the question. I would like to know if when using the second method described above, if it's possible to only allow the login (assuming the PIN is correct) **ONLY if that link has been clicked in a specific website**.

The way it works now, anyone with the link could use it to login into website 1. I want to prevent that, I want to allow that to happen if that link has been clicked win website 2.

The idea would be to "detect" the referring website in the login function, and only allow it if it matches the URL (or any other unique identifier) of website 2.

If using a "plain" link would not allow for this that wouldn't be a problem, I'm flexible as to what way I could use for this, but in the end it would need to be something that only meant a click for the users in website 2.

**EDIT**

I think it's good to add this since some of the comments/responses talk about the security of doing this (which is great of course). The main reason to do this is to "force" the users to visit website 2 before going to website 1. Basically so they can't enter that URL in their browser and log into website 1, I want to only be able to use that link if they're clicking it from website 2. I explain this because security is not a huge factor here, if a few savy users can get around whatever method I implement it's not a big deal, it's more important that the method is as simple as possible to implement in website 2 (since I don't run that website and I will need to ask people there to do whatever is needed).

Comment: are these websites in the same domain? if yes, then have you considered handling this through session, cookie, local storage, etc? Your suggested way bears no security enforcement what so ever, so you would be better off using a query parameter instead. i.e. pass a query parameter in the first website that indicates the login should be shown.

Comment: @Aidin both websites they are in different servers, I'll edit the questions to clarify that, thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to both servers?

Comment: Have you thought about checking $_SERVER[”HTTP_REFERER"]? Not very secure, as the referer can be faked easily. But high security does not seem to be of great concern.

Comment: nope, just website 1, the second server is run by different people who would collaborate for this matter but I won't have access to it

Comment: Based on your edit: If security is not a concern, use the HTTP_REFERER as detailed in one of the answers and comments. But please be aware that some company browsers (and some scary vpns if your connection is not encrypted) and some privacy tools strip this header away. Other option is to create a token and add it to the query-string and embed a timestamp in a way that will allow you to extract and validate it on the target server (maybe using encryption using a shared key between origin and target server). Still not safe, but would require some time to figure out.

Comment: @halfer running PHP there should be fine

Comment: @Rangad: Albert and I both posted answers similar in approach to your comment. Good thinking!

Comment: I recommend you to use SSO. Don't pass around the sensitive info such as username, password, and pins through the Urls. http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201206x1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Comment: @Aidin thanks for the suggestion, I just think that SSO would be an overkill in this case, those PINs are temporary, they're not like username/password chosen by the user

Comment: Upvoted since seems these conversations would be of good educational value for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for a variation of Single Sign On. This is a technique in which an authentication in one site is recognised transparently in another. Here is how it works in your case.

Normally you would have a link in site2.com like this:

> http://site1.com/login.php?pin=123456789

However, site1.com cannot tell from the referrer which site it has really come from, since it it can be trivially faked. Of course, that may not matter for your use case, if you only want a simple level of security. But if you want something better, read on!

You can use a hashing system and a shared secret, to create something that can only have come from one source. Both sites have the same shared secret, stored in a file. We'll call that `$sharedSecret`. The algorithm goes like this:

```
$hash = hashFunction($pin . $sharedSecret);
```

Then you can do this in site2.com:

```
<a
    href="http://site1.com/login.php?pin=<?php echo (int) $pin ?>&amp;hash=<?php echo $hash ?>"
    alt="Authenticated link"
>
```

When site1.com sees it, it can get the PIN straight away, repeat the algorithm, and check that the hash really did come from site2.com. If you have several referring sites, then site1.com should store a separate secret for all of them, and then it can securely check the referrer to see which one it should load.

The shared secret should be substantial enough that it cannot be guessed; I tend to go for around 40-60 characters.

However, the remaining flaw in this plan is that someone could visit site2.com and steal a link from them, and it would still work, providing they were also willing to fake the referrer every time they wanted access. It may therefore be useful to add a timestamp into the algorithm too:

```
// The time is rounded to the nearest 500 seconds, to account for
// out of sync clocks. Adjust this depending on how long you want links to
// remain active for
$time = floor(time() / 500) * 500;
$hash = hashFunction($pin . $sharedSecret . $time);
```

Then on site1.com you should compute two hashes:

- One for `floor(time() / 500) * 500`
- One for `floor(time() / 500) * 500 - 500`

If the supplied hash matches either, allow the link to unlock the content. This accounts for the possibility that the time went over a +/-500 boundary between one server and the next.

I haven't mentioned a specific hashing function here. SHA256 should be fine, but note I'm not a cryptographer. If you want more security again, it may be worth checking to ensure someone isn't brute-forcing the system by flooding your system with guesses - though over the internet it is hardly worth their trying.

Comment: thanks for the response! I actually posted my own response at the same time, which happens to use the same idea! Although mine only uses the PIN and the timestamp, no sharedSecret, I'm trying to understand if it's really necessary or not

Comment: passing the pin using the query string? Bad Idea

Comment: after considering the new information (PIN is temporary and is bound to a timeout) then this would be valid answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is multi-faceted.  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is available to PHP, but can be spoofed or omitted and is considered unreliable.

Cross-domain cookies are a bit of a challenge as well; I understand it's possible, but haven't yet found time to implement it (we have a use case at work).  At any rate, cookies, are also quite exploitable.

Possibly your best bet would be to have the link point on "Site A" point to a resource also on "Site A" that sets a random key/token and timestamp into a shared database and fowards the browser to "Site B" with that token.  The receiving page on "Site B" would then verify the existence of the key/token in the GET string, check for its existence in the database and possibly match the User-Agent and Referer data and checking that the time was within $smallnum seconds after the timestamp entry for that key/token.

Comment: Aside: [w3.org has a working example of your #1, using `HTTP_REFERER`](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SVR3.html).

Comment: But most people around here could get around the limitation without opening any extra windows. The safest bet might be to track the link click on the first side using js, have the origin server notify the target server that a user is comming and then redirect the user to the new location and validate that the token sent by the origin server matches the token associated with the current request. Or if this scenario is to complex have throw away tokens appended to the link and live with the chance that the system can be avoided with some effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this answer that I came out with thanks to the other answers/comments made by fellow SO users. I think it's a pretty simple method (simplicity is good in this case), and that it should work, but of course if it has any big flaw I'd be great to know :)

Like I say in the OP, security (in terms of some savvy user getting around this and using the link directly instead of from website 2) isn't a huge deal here, we can deal with a small number of exceptions.

Here's the idea:

- Give the user in website 2 a link to a function in that same domain
- That function grabs the PIN (i.e. 1234567890) that each user will have, and the current timestamp (i.e. 1417812842), creating a token using those 2 values, using another function that both websites will know (some sort of hashing with salt, for example)
- Generate a redirect from website 2 to website 1, with a URL that includes the PIN and the token, something like: `http://myURL.com/process_login_request.php?pin=123456789&token=abc123def456`
- A function in `process_login_request.php`, using the same function that was used to generate the token in website 2, will generate a number of tokens for the past X seconds (let's say 10 seconds), using the PIN and the timestamps for the past 10 seconds.
- If any of the generated tokens match the received token means that the request was OK, and we allow the login

I think it's easier to implement than to explain though. The idea basically is that we use timestamps in a short period of time (the time between the user "clicks" the link that should take him to website 1 and the time he actually lands on website 1). I said 10 seconds, but we could increase that as necessary if 10 seconds is too short (which I think it shouldn't be).

Comment: passing the pin using the query string? Bad Idea

Comment: @Aidin thanks for the feedback, I would like to know why it's a bad idea though...

Comment: What would be the alternative and how would it be *more secure*? (Admittedly, the implementation could be altered)

Comment: 1. It will show up in user's browser history 2. User can bookmark the url and effectively bypass the first website 3. It is a plain view and any body overlooking the pin can see it

Comment: As the token would only be valid for a couple seconds the danger in that would be negligible

Comment: @Aidin well, that link he bookmarked wouldn't work after the 10 seconds threshold anyways... so he would have to go back to website 2 to click again in the link, which is exactly what I want

Comment: "I have a PHP/MySQL website (website 1) that has a login system that only asks for a PIN code" .... well how secure is your website if some one see your PIN in history and tries to login directly from website 1?

Comment: @Albert As a note: You might want to generate the token in the click-event handler of the link (and load it using ajax from the server site) as it may become invalid in the time a user reads through the origin page.

Comment: @Aidin I've oversimplified in the explanation of website 1 because that aspect that your mentioning isn't relevant to the matter of my question. It is relevant the part that the PIN could be stored in the browser's history, in which case I think the method is still valid, only that it would be good to find a way to avoid that from happening (for example using javascript, like Rangad mentions, or transmitting the URL via POST instead of a direct redirect, or I'm sure there are other ways to prevent that)

Comment: @Rangad thanks for the advice, but I can't seem to see in what situation that would happen (the token becoming invalid), would you mind giving an exmple?

Comment: I visit the first page, my boss/wife/random stranger on im-service asks me something and I leave the computer for some minutes.

Comment: @Aidin: your criticisms are worth consideration, but I can't see they are valid in this case. 1. Yes, it will show up in the browser history. It cannot be played back though, if it has a time component. 2. User cannot realistically bypass the first website, no (unless by that you mean they visit that website and use the link themselves - but I think we are guarding against republishing here, and they cannot reasonably do that without the shared secret). 3. Yes, anyone can see the PIN, but it is useless without a recently generated hash.

Comment: @Rangad OK I get what you mean. In the solution I proposed that wouldn't happen (I probably didn't explain that part very well, it's the first point). The token isn't generated until the user clicks on the link to access website 1, so it all happens almost instantly

Comment: @Rangad, you don't need AJAX for this - a redirect to the same server to get the hash, then to the remote server, would do just fine - much simpler! But good point about links going stale.