# How a login server works?

Tags: authentication, server

Since I'm new, I would like to start with a question which I cannot find a proper answer searching for it on Google or everywhere on the net.

I'm not such a master in server things since I am a novice just at a administrative level, but how a login server looks like and which tools is using to act as a login domain and then querying all the request? It sounds like a RDBMS?

Consider this question as I don't know a single thing about it, since I know just the basics somewhere about Active directories, Domains, etc.

Comment: Do you mean a [single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) server?

Comment: Yeah, something similar to SSO mechanism, or in other words understands the procedure in how a login server stores the data (like with games where they have a login server in order to access into the game). I usually know a part where DB can store information and then querying them when the users needs it, but nothing else than some basics about other procedures as you mention it.

Also this question is related in a similar way for business purposes. Just to expand my knowledges about it. In the future I'd like to make some experiment with authentication procedures. :)

Comment: For web-based SSO, I've outlined a [simple version here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27324950/472495). Games that are not based on the web will be simpler - they'll just use HTTP to send a username and a hashed password to the server, which will reply with a success/fail flag. It'll probably run over HTTPs.

Answer (score 0):

In case your question is how to create a login form, database, authentication, and keep the users logged in then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477578/4305122) has everything you need.

Comment: Well the question was all about how a login server act and works, means how it keeps the system secured, which protocols is using to prevent external attacks (bruteforce, DOS, etc.), which kind of DBs are using to store user credentials (Oracle? MySQL? MSSQL?) ... But since I specified in the end that I also like to make experiments in this kind of system, then yes the solution is useful and I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot for everyone! In case of some further questions I will answer it here.

Comment: @Providence: any database can be used to store credentials - either a relational type like the ones you list, or a NoSQL/document store.